# how to use jwt in php and test with postman?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, postman, token

i try using jwt php in codeigniter and test with postman.
my code

```
public function index_get(){
$authHeader = $this->input->get_request_header('Authorization');
$arr = explode(" ", $authHeader);
$jwt = isset($arr[1])? $arr[1] : "";
$secretkey = base64_encode("gampang");

if ($jwt) {
    try {
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $secretkey, array('HS256'));

        $id = $this->get('BookID');
        if ($id=='') {
            $data = $this->db->get('book')->result();
        } else {
            $this->db->where('BookID', $id);
            $data = $this->db->get('book')->result();
        }
        $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
        "code"=>200,
        "message"=>"Response successfully",
        "data"=>$data];
        $this->response($result, 200);
    } catch (Exception $e){

        $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
        "code"=>401,
        "message"=>"Access denied",
        "data"=>null];
        $this->response($result, 401);
    }
}else {
    $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
    "code"=>401,
    "message"=>"Access denied",
    "data"=>null];
    $this->response($result, 401);
}
```

when i test with postman. it gives me in postman

```
{
"took": 1639442842.209898,
"code": 401,
"message": "Access denied",
"data": null
```

}

and token didnt show. it gives me null. whats wrong with mycode? can anybody help.?

Comment: What's the exception message? check that `$jwt` is what it's supposed to be. We cant tell from here.

Comment: i think access denied like postman and data null, my code didnt catch If($jwt){ }. i dont know why. can you help. im knew in php